# "Call to undefined method Intervention\Image\Image::make()"

Tags: php, laravel

When I used Laravel Intervention image in localhost then it's working perfect but this when upload live server in my control panel then it's not working...

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's Java code

Comment: First of all, there is two semi-colon at the end of the line.

Comment: Yep that's PHP with the Laravel framework not java... Can you give us the full file? Are you sure you're using the `Image` facade, and not the class? Have you run `composer install` ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!
First of all (as @MauricePerry already stated): The code you posted is no java code, but PHP (have a look at the file extension). Secondly it would be great if you post your code as a snipped instead of a picture. Moreover a more detailed description of what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far as solution.

Comment: i'm already run composer and working localhost but not work live server

Comment: on Live can you check if the intervention package is installed inside `vendor` folder. If its present then try running `composer dump-autoload` and check again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in config/app.php

In the $providers array add the service providers for this package.

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

Add the facade of this package to the $aliases array.

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

according to this link http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

or at the head of your controller add this after installing it:-

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
```

Comment: do not put in links. Your one is dead now.